# Determine if any cells in a column range equal to 0, final result is 0, or else is 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Sorry if my title is confusing. I'm new to Logical formula in excel but I need it to achieve something now. I had check the internet for the formula but found it abit confusing and not sure what method i should use.

This is my situation:
I have an excel consists over 50+ rows. In each row, there are 5 different columns holding a value of either 1 or 0 with one extra column to determine the final value, which is something like below:

A1 = 0, B1 = 1, C1 = 0, D1 = 1, E1 = 1, F1 = (Final Value)

What I need is the logical statement to check if any cells from A1 to E1 consist of 0, then F1 will be equal to 0, else if all cells value is 1, then F1 is equal to 2.

As i said before, there over 50+ rows with the same thing, each line consists of 5 columns with a value of 1 or 0, and finally one extra column that hold the final value of 0 or 2 according to the 5 columns.

Kindly let me know any method i can use to achieve my needs or if there is any better solution to deal with all the rows which are basically the same thing.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7):

I like Gary's Student's for cleverness, but for clarity, I like:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,0)=0,2,0)
```

Comment: Actually, Doug, I agree with you.  Your approach is self-documenting.  My approach smells of wizardry.

Comment: For me it also worked with text: `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,"text")=0,2,0)`

Answer (score 4):

How about something like:

**=MIN(A1:E1)*2**

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this wouldn't end up giving the correct result, because when there is a 1, the lowest value in the range might still be a 0!

Comment: The poster wants to get 0 if **ANY** value is zero....regardless if there is a single **1** or more than a single **1** .....that is why MIN works!